# Using Coredll.dll to retrieve information on stores

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I'm trying to use Coredll.dll in C# to retrieve data on the stores that are mounted.

Here are my structs that are supposed to mimic the structs in the native library ([STORAGEDEVICEINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms892022.aspx), [STORAGEINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms892106.aspx))

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct STORAGEDEVICEINFO
{
    public DWORD cbSize;
    public fixed System.UInt16 szProfile[32];
    public DWORD dwDeviceClass;
    public DWORD dwDeviceType;
    public DWORD dwDeviceFlags;

}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct STOREINFO
{
    public DWORD cbSize;
    public fixed System.UInt16 szDeviceName[8];
    public fixed System.UInt16 szStoreName[32];
    public DWORD dwDeviceClass;
    public DWORD dwDeviceType;
    public STORAGEDEVICEINFO sdi;
    public DWORD dwDeviceFlags;
    public SECTORNUM snNumSectors;
    public DWORD dwBytesPerSector;
    public SECTORNUM snFreeSectors;
    public SECTORNUM snBiggestPartCreatable;
    public DWORD ftCreated; /* ? */
    public DWORD ftLastModified;
    public DWORD dwAttributes;
    public DWORD dwPartitionCount;
    public DWORD dwMountCount;
}
```

Here is my FindStoreInfo call (`HANDLE` is just an `IntPtr`):

```
    [DllImport("Coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern HANDLE FindFirstStore(STOREINFO *info/*PSTOREINFO pStoreInfo*/);
```

The function calls without an error BUT it's not changing `info`. It leaves it as a blank struct except for cbSize (but that is changed from the sizeof call). This is where I am calling it.

```
        STOREINFO info;
        info.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STOREINFO));
        Store.StorageManager.FindFirstStore(&info);
```

Calling GetLastError returns 0x57, which is "ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER". I'm not sure why it'd return this because all I am looking for is the pointer.

Comment: Are you saying that the size you send in and the size you get back are different?  If so, that's telling you something - mainly that your definition is incorrect.

Comment: Nah, I'm saying the struct isn't affected by the function. The `cbSize` isn't changed by the function, but it's changed by the sizeof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `cbSize` is probably wrong. Try changing
`public fixed char szProfile[32];` to `public fixed System.UInt16 szProfile[32];`

Also, `FILETIME` is a two DWORD structure, not one DWORD.

Comment: Tried it but having the same issue still.

Comment: What is the value of cbsize being passed in? And fix the size of the two FILETIME structures.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the FILETIME structs to QWORDS fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but maybe it can help somebody else:

The following structures work for me, notice the Marshalling:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct STORAGEDEVICEINFO
{
    public DWORD cbSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string szProfile;
    public DWORD dwDeviceClass;
    public DWORD dwDeviceType;
    public DWORD dwDeviceFlags;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct STOREINFO
{
    public DWORD cbSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
    public string szDeviceName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string szStoreName;
    public DWORD dwDeviceClass;
    public DWORD dwDeviceType;
    public STORAGEDEVICEINFO sdi;
    public DWORD dwDeviceFlags;
    public SECTORNUM snNumSectors;
    public DWORD dwBytesPerSector;
    public SECTORNUM snFreeSectors;
    public SECTORNUM snBiggestPartCreatable;
    public FILETIME ftCreated;
    public FILETIME ftLastModified;
    public DWORD dwAttributes;
    public DWORD dwPartitionCount;
    public DWORD dwMountCount;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct PARTINFO
{
    public DWORD cbSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string szPartitionName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string szFileSys;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string szVolumeName;
    public SECTORNUM snNumSectors;
    public FILETIME ftCreated;
    public FILETIME ftLastModified;
    public DWORD dwAttributes;
    public BYTE bPartType;
}
```

Also I learnt that you can pass structs by reference to the P/Invoke calls:

```
    [DllImport("Coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern HANDLE FindFirstStore(ref STOREINFO storeInfo);

    [DllImport("Coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool FindNextStore(HANDLE hSearch, ref STOREINFO storeInfo);
```

And the calls:

```
STOREINFO si = new STOREINFO();
HANDLE hSearch = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

si.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STOREINFO));

// enumerate first store
hSearch = StorageManager.FindFirstStore(ref si);
```